# Where can I get a high res terrain map for DotA 2?

Tags: dota-2

I am trying to find high resolution DotA 2 terrain maps, but found nothing. Can somebody help me find some similar to [this one](http://www.dotadudes.co.cc/2009/06/new-dota-terrain-map-layout-660.html)?

Comment: I would suggest looking for it in the steam workshop, there might be one there

Answer (score 2):

Googled 'dota2 map'

First image:

[image: Dota2 High-Res map]

Here's a high-res version of the minimap

[image: Dota2 High-Res minimap]

Comment: I was referring to a map that would have been glued together from pieces displayed on the screen during the game. Or something like that.

Comment: @gnusarev I'm not sure that you'll find one mainly due to the angle of the DoTA view would make it hard to stich I think.

Comment: You can try looking through the console settings and see if there's a way to orient the camera from a top-down point of view or zoom out. If those commands are accessible you can probably make one yourself pretty easily.

Comment: [Here's a more recent version reflecting the changes in 6.86](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/File:Minimap_6.86.png).